# How to show location address using every set of latitude and longitude stored in FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geocode, reversegeocodelocation

I have 3 sets of latitude and longitude stored in `FirebaseDatabase`.

What I am doing is I am retrieving these stored sets and showing location address using them.

Here's my code:

```
databaseReference.child("child").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String, String> newRequest = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                currentLat = newRequest.get("currentLat");
                currentLng = newRequest.get("currentLng");

                currentLatDouble = Double.parseDouble(currentLat);
                currentLngDouble = Double.parseDouble(currentLng);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeocodeAddressIntentService.class);
                intent.putExtra(RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
                intent.putExtra(LOCATION_LATITUDE_DATA_EXTRA, currentLatDouble);
                intent.putExtra(LOCATION_LONGITUDE_DATA_EXTRA, currentLngDouble);
                startService(intent);

                }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here's `GeocodeAddressIntentService.java` file's code:

```
public class GeocodeAddressIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int SUCCESS_RESULT = 0;
    public static final int FAILURE_RESULT = 1;
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
            "com.abc.xyz";
    public static final String RESULT_DATA_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RESULT_DATA_KEY";
    public static final String RESULT_ADDRESS = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RESULT_ADDRESS";
    public static final String LOCATION_LATITUDE_DATA_EXTRA = PACKAGE_NAME + ".LOCATION_LATITUDE_DATA_EXTRA";
    public static final String LOCATION_LONGITUDE_DATA_EXTRA = PACKAGE_NAME + ".LOCATION_LONGITUDE_DATA_EXTRA";
    public static final String RECEIVER = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RECEIVER";

    protected android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    private static final String TAG = "GEO_ADDY_SERVICE";
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    Location location;

    public GeocodeAddressIntentService() {
        super("GeocodeAddressIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
        double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra(LOCATION_LATITUDE_DATA_EXTRA, 0);
        double longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra(LOCATION_LONGITUDE_DATA_EXTRA, 0);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getCountryName());
            }

            resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);

            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }

            deliverResultToReceiver(SUCCESS_RESULT,
                    address.getLocality() + ", " + address.getCountryName(), address);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            deliverResultToReceiver(FAILURE_RESULT, e.getMessage(), null);
        }

    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message, Address address) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(RESULT_ADDRESS, address);
        bundle.putString(RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
        if (resultReceiver != null) {
            resultReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Some error occurred. Try restarting the app.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

What's going wrong is that the name of location is not getting shown according to every sets of latitude and longitude but according to the last/latest saved set of latitude and longitude.

Please let me know how can I show location address according to every set of latitude and longitude retrieved from the database?

Comment: Add `Log` statements to `onChildAdded()`, `onHandleIntent()`, `deliverResultToReceiver(`), and your ResultReceiver's `onReceiveResult()` to show intermediate results and to give you some understanding of the execution flow.  With those insights you can probably solve this problem yourself.  If not, post the `logcat` output.

Comment: I think they are all getting sent, but only the last one is being displayed because you are only storing/setting the last value. Instead of using a ChildEventListener you could use ValueEventListener and then send all of the values at one time.